# How to make a DAX measure NOT to re-calculate on aggregated levels?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, power-query, dax

I have a DAX measure which works perfectly on the level 0 POV in the Pivot Table but I was wondering if there is a way to make it aggregate like a regular number when filtering to top level POV (e.g. instead of looking at July or August, look at Year Total)?

The problem is the aggregated number on the calculated column != the number if it was aggregated in the Planning system in a regular number column

Answer (score 0):

There are functions available to test if a column has a single value - the best is SELECTEDVALUE. You can combine the result of that with an IF function to achieve what you want, along the lines of:

```
= IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Dates[Year] , 99999 ) = 9999 , "Multiple Years" , "Single Year" )
```